# How to find number of pages returned by a OneNote API search?

Tags: rest, onenote, onenote-api

Is there any easy way to find the number of pages returned by a OneNote API search with GET?

Answer (score 4):

Use the count=true query parameter in GET ~pages API.

[Support for $count](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/onenotedev/archive/2015/02/09/page-query-and-full-text-search-apis-now-available-in-production.aspx)
We now support the OData $count verb so you can get the total number of pages in the collection. Good for paging. E.g. https://www.onenote.com/api/v1.0/pages?count=true

Comment: Excellent Dipak! Just what I need. Many thanks for your prompt answer. I missed seeing that in the API documentation.